# MATLAB - Use a user-defined class method in parallel on GPU

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, gpu

Let's say I have a class named *Stack* and it has a method that takes some other properties of Stack objects as input arguments which consist of vectors and scalars. The input vectors and output matrix **change sizes** depending on the object.

```matlab
classdef Stack
...
...

function out = some_method(scalar1,scalar2,...,vec1,vec2...) % out has different number of 
                                                             % columns depending on the size of vec1,vec2 etc.
...
out = ... % size of (4,m) where m changes for each object
end
```

This specific method of Stack should be called **thousands of times** to be used in another script for some other purpose. Since it takes time to use this method serially, a parallel solution will save a lot of time for bigger calculations.

I attempted to use **cellfun** by passing the indices of Stack objects inside a function hoping that I could run it on my GPU but cellfun doesn't support GPU computing. I also tried to use **arrayfun** but it doesn't support UniformOutput parameter on GPUs. I can't store different sizes of outputs inside a cell if I want to use my GPU.

My question is, is parallel computing on GPU possible for a class method/function that returns different sizes of outputs each time? If not, what could be a possible workaround for this problem?

Update: A short summary of my problem is; I would like to run the same function in parallel for each Stack object with their own inputs individually, knowing that their outputs don't match in sizes and collect them in a cell array at the end.

Comment: Its not clear what you really want. Of course GPU computing support different sizes of inputs and outputs, as an example, take 2 matrices of random (yet compatible) size and multiply them using `gpuArray`. You will need to be specific with your problem

Comment: @AnderBiguri by different sizes of input and output, I meant that for each iteration, the input and output sizes change for each class object. For instance, for the first time I'm calling the method, one of the input vectors has the size (1,20) and as a result, the output will be (4,20) for the first iteration. For the second time I'm calling the method, let's say the input will have the size (1,18) and output (4,18). I want to be able to account for this size change between the iterations and call the method several times to get the output at once in a cell array.

Comment: GPU computing is a technique to do the same thing, many times, in parallel. GPUs can not do different things with each processor. That is simply now how they work. You can put in the gpu "the same task" x10000 times, but you 10000 different tasks once.